# Failed Ubuntu install - installing newer version

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, partitioning

I have been using 12.04 for the last couple of months and just tried to update to 12.10 ( via the update manager). After the update & reboot I get to GRUB (Machine dual boots with Windows 7) and then I get the purple Ubuntu Screen - after that I only get a black screen with a white cursor in the top left corner (not blinking) and the machine freezes.

I have decided to do a clean install of 14.04 once a stable release is out (17/04) - how can I make sure I put this new install on the same partitions as my current 12.04 is on and therefore leave the windows partitions untouched? What is the best way to identify which are the windows partitions and which the ubuntu ones? As I can't start Ubuntu anymore I have to do this via Windows 7. I used diskmgmnt.msc but cannot really tell which are which partitions.

Comment: If have an AMD graphics card and using the proprietary drivers, you may want to uninstall them. That has caused crashes after upgrades earlier.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the installer, you will be given the option to upgrade Ubuntu or to erase and reinstall. You don't have to think about the technical details such as partitioning at all.

I took a screenshot for you so you can see what it looks like. If your system doesn't work now and you're going to install 14.04LTS later, then there's not really any reason to wait. Just install upgrades as they arrive and you'll be in the finished product when it's released. And although it's beta, I've been running it for months and it's quite stable and nice.

[image]